Could sexual risk orders be applied to offences not listed in the sexual offences act 2003?
This question really relates to the broadly termed sexual activity specified by the sexual risk order and whether it has been used for sexual activities that fell outside the sexual offences act 2003 in England and Wales.
For example outraging public decency isn't in the soa 2003 but can involve a sexual element which could attract harm prevention or risk orders.
Similarly I am aware of a somerset police officer that was not convicted of disclosing sexual images without consent but was made subject to a sexual harm prevention order nonetheless.
If a sexual element was found to be the case under the old s.33 disclosure of sexual images without consent offence, could a SRO be applied for? Is there any case law supporting that?
Similarly has any SRO been imposed on people convicted or arrested under s.127 of the communications offences act as I'm aware that had also been used to deal with non consensual image sharing.

This question concerns both "sexual risk orders" and "sexual harm prevention orders", which are not the same thing. An SRO can apply to conduct that falls short of any criminal offence, and indeed is meant for that scenario.
Currently, a SHPO can be made under authority of the Sentencing Act 2020, and is available as part of sentencing for certain offences (s.345). Those include various sexual offences but also other serious offences that are not intrinsically sexual. In either event, the court can make  a SHPO for the purpose of protecting members of the public from the risk of sexual harm (essentially, harm resulting from the commission of one of the listed sexual offences). The example in the question regarding s.127 of the Communications Act 2003 is an example of one of those other offences - see paragraph 61A. So somebody who was convicted of improper use of a public electronic communications network could have an SHPO made against them, if the court was satisfied that the nature of the improper use made that appropriate.
Meanwhile, a SRO is a preventative order which can be issued by the magistrate's court on the application of the police. A trigger condition is that the person has "done an act of a sexual nature" (Sexual Offences Act 2003, s.122A(2)), to be proved on the balance of probabilities, and that the court believes it is necessary to make the order for the purpose of protecting the public.
Although they have similarities, the main point is that an SRO is not confined to situations where someone has just been convicted of an offence. If they had then they might get a SHPO. Statutory guidance on SROs emphasizes:

A Sexual Risk Order (SRO) is a civil order which can be sought by the police against an
individual who has not been convicted, cautioned etc. of a Schedule 3 or Schedule 5 offence
(or any other offence) but who is nevertheless thought to pose a risk of harm.

and:

The overriding principle is that an SRO should never be pursued in the alternative to a
prosecution where conduct is criminal.

The guidance, concerning the term "acts of a sexual nature", also says this "covers acts that may not in
themselves be sexual but have a sexual motive and/or are intended to allow the perpetrator
to move on to sexual abuse." All this is to say that SROs are specifically meant for situations where the person concerned has not been convicted of any relevant offence.
The High Court in Chief Constable of Kent Police v Carter [2022] EWHC 1972 (Admin) agreed (para 20):

[I]t is not necessary to prove that the respondent committed a criminal offence. Were that the case, the power to make a sexual risk order would have no point. Where there is sufficient evidence to convict somebody of a criminal offence, the presumption must be that prosecution would follow. On conviction, there are ample powers to make a protective order without resorting to s.122A.

The Court of Appeal has also indicated that sentencing guidelines for SHPO breaches are not directly applicable to SRO breaches, since "it must be borne in mind that a person in breach of a sexual risk order may not have been [...] convicted of any sexual offence". (R v Mayne [2021] EWCA Crim 737).
An SRO can be made against somebody who was found not guilty of an offence that would have qualified for a SHPO. Recall that the standard of proof for an SRO is lower than for a criminal conviction. This was the case with John O'Neill who was acquitted of rape in the Crown Court, but had an SRO imposed. It's also plausible that, as in the question, there could be an SRO against somebody arrested but not charged, for the same reasons.
